# 2 CMFCTabControls on different position, but tabs stay on the same place

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I've would like to have 2 sets of tabs on my CScrollView -derived class, so I put 2 CMFCTabCtrs side by side. The tab controls are filled with dialogs (currently same class, but different objects for test purpose, later different dialogs for each tab control).

The problem is while the controls themselves are placed besides each other as desired. the tabs or dialogs from the second tab control appear in area of the first tab controls, thus overlapping with it.
[image]

on the picture above the dialog  on the left (currently minimalistic for testing) actually belongs to the control on the right. the dialogs inside of tab are childs of the view.

Resource of the dialog:

```
IDD_COMBATANTDLG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 320, 331
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    GROUPBOX        "Flotte",IDC_STATIC,19,18,192,175,BS_FLAT
    LTEXT           "Static",IDC_STATIC,91,94,19,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,136,118,40,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
END
```

declarations:

```
class SimDataInput : public CScrollView
{
protected: // create from serialization only
    SimDataInput();
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(SimDataInput)

// Attributes
private:

    CMFCTabCtrl combatant_tabs[2];//tabs
    std::vector<CombatantDlg*> p2combatdlg[2];//stores pointers to dialog
    const CStringW attdef[2] = { L"Angreifer ", L"Verteidiger " };//standard labels for respective tab controls
```

............

from OnInitialUpdate():

```
void SimDataInput::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CScrollView::OnInitialUpdate();
    for (auto i = 0; i < 2;i++)
{
        CStringW label ( attdef[i]);
        RECT pos = RECT{ i * 400, 0, 400 + i * 400, 500 };
    combatant_tabs[i].Create(CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D, pos, this,10000+i, CMFCTabCtrl::LOCATION_TOP,TRUE);//create tab
    combatant_tabs[i].EnableTabSwap(FALSE);
    combatant_tabs[i].EnableActiveTabCloseButton();
    //combatant_tabs[sim::ATT].EnableTabDocumentsMenu(TRUE);
    p2combatdlg[i].reserve(16);
    p2combatdlg[i].emplace_back();//create pointer
    p2combatdlg[i].back() = new CombatantDlg(this);//initialize pointer to the new dialog
    p2combatdlg[i].back()->Create(IDD_COMBATANTDLG, this);//create dialog
    //p2combatdlg[i].back()->SetWindowPos(&combatant_tabs[i], 400, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);//tried this -doesn't help
        label.AppendFormat(L"%d",1);
    combatant_tabs[i].InsertTab(p2combatdlg[i].back(),label , 0, -1, FALSE);//insert the first tab
    }
```

.......
next function inserts new tabs after pushing respective button

```
void SimDataInput::OnCombatant(UINT nID)//used by ON_COMMAND_RANGE for both tab controls
{
    nID -= ID_ATTACKER;

    if (combatant_tabs[nID].GetTabsNum() == 16)
        return; 
    CStringW label ( attdef[nID]);
    p2combatdlg[nID].emplace_back();
    label.AppendFormat(L"%d", p2combatdlg[nID].size());
    p2combatdlg[nID].back() = new CombatantDlg(this);
    p2combatdlg[nID].back()->Create(IDD_COMBATANTDLG, this);
    combatant_tabs[nID].InsertTab(p2combatdlg[nID].back(), label , combatant_tabs[nID].GetTabsNum(), -1, FALSE);
    combatant_tabs[nID].SetActiveTab(combatant_tabs[nID].GetTabsNum() - 1);
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
}
```

Comment: Typically the controls are not children of the tab, but children of the tab's parent, so this might be part of the cause. Other than that we will need to see more code related to the placement of the tabbed dialogs.

Comment: Typically the controls are not children of the tab, but children of the tab's parent
-that's the case here

Comment: If you've not yet solved it, can you show more code pls?

Comment: ok, you have asked for it :). here is all relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, making the CMFCTabCtrls parents to the contained dialog corrected the behaviour. I had to store the pointer to the former parentsd insidethe dialogs to make the access easier